# How can I calculate the neutral load in a single phase circuit with disparate bus loads?

Tags: electrical

In a 240 volt single phase, bus A has 4000 watt load and bus B has 7000 watt load . WHAT IS THE NEUTRAL LOAD?

Comment: Are you on 120/240 *split-phase* power (North American), or IEC (5-continent) 230V single phase?

Comment: Are these both 120v loads? Usually at this size they would be 240 v unless you added everything up on each leg for 120v then the neutral would be 3000 as blatsplaterson answered. But the question would be why are you asking this because the neutral sizing is regulated by code. See 250.102.c.1 for the table

Answer (score 1):

In typical split phase service, the neutral carries the imbalance of the current between the two legs, so the neutral load would be

(7000-4000)W

or 3000W.

Answer (score 0):

11000 watts *and it's illegal*.  Two hots can't share a neutral under "just any" condition; only under *certain conditions* and you have not named one of them.

If you correctly engineered it to be one of the other conditions, particularly split-phase, the answer is 7000W because you can't count on that 4000W load *staying on*, the neutral must be able to handle worst case.

Comment: A neutral must be sized to the maximum possible load of any one phase that is not a 240V load (a 120/240V load carries current on the neutral). So the 4KW and the 7KW is immaterial as Harper has stated. To top things off, loads need to be balanced between phases to no more than 10% difference.

Comment: In a house with a standard panel approx half of the 1-pole breakers are on one leg and half on the other. But it could be that the loads are unbalanced by more than 10%, couldn't it?

Comment: Code only states balanced it does not specify a value but I agree that 10% is a good target.

Comment: @JimStewart Loads can be unbalanced by 0% to 100%.  Or 110% if they're really, really committed!    Also, if Spinal Tap or My Bloody Valentine are involved, all bets are off.  So you have to design for that happening.   It's basically being a good neighbor to *try* to balance your practical loads, especially if you're the biggest load in the town.  Oh, and panels whose number of slots is 12 or more and not a mulltiple of 4, are not quite balanced.

Comment: So how would you connect a single phase load on a transformer wired as star (wye)? Neutral is 'shared' across phases by definition. EX: how would you connect 4 220V loads (A B C D) over a 380V 3-phase connecion. I'll spread them across phases with neutral as 'common'. A,B across R and N, C across S and N, D across T and N.

Comment: @DDS you misread my second sentence, it is a compound sentence and it has a second half.  I see where I could have written it better. Edited.  In any case, what you describe is inclusive to the second half of the sentence, it's a case where it *is* allowed *because* it's 3-phase.  If it was 3 random breakers in a random panel, then no.

Comment: @Harper 3 'random' breakers in 3 'random' panels could easly be served by the same neutral as it comes from the center of the transformer (and a transformer has only 1 center tap). In a consumer unit is obvious that each circuit must have its own neutral 'coming back', because if it's not the RCD will be tripping all the time. So, our freind, the OP, for 2 phase a circuit (230V in US) he could just pull a single neutral from the RCD in the CU that has to be same size as the phase(s) wire(s). If he's talking about 2 127V circuits no, he have to run 2 neutral wires each coming from its own RCD.

Comment: @DDS exactly... my concern is this may not be obvious to OP or other random passersby. I want to emphasize that the situations when you can share neutrals are fairly special, even if we're good at making them special.

Comment: It depends on where you live, here in EU most homes has 3phase so what you say 'special thing' is the norm, it's NEC system that is weird: using 'split phase' that, if you think at it, is weird. Having a 3 phase 225V Live-Live + center tapped neutral would be better for both power company that have loads better balanced across their lines also for the customer that if the company loose a phase won't go totally dark because will have another (or other 2) phases

Answer (score 0):

You should get a wire as thick as phase wire, on industrial balanced loads (230/400V), if phase conductors are thicker than 16mm^2 it could thinner with a minimum of 16mm^2.

In your case (wire thinner than 16mm^2) your neutral must be as thick as phase conductor

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple. if you have a 20 amp circuit on A phase, put the next 20 amp circuit on B phase. If its a 3 phase system, put the third 20 amp circuit on C phase. ect. It's not brain surgery.

Comment: keep it simple and always wire the neutral the same size as the current carrying conductors.  Only downsize the equipment ground according to NEC.  I'm in the USA so I don't know how people overseas are governed.  The goal would be to have the neutral load to be zero.  Because that will never happen you should assume the max neutral load will occur.  Just size the neutral the same size as the current carrying conductors.  If the Neutral is overloaded the main will trip.  Then the electrical contractor will have some explaining to do about how he balanced the panel.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming, but you should edit your answer to have all the info you added in your comment. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.